# Why does NSLog format text correctly, but NSMutableArray does not?

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser, nsmutabledictionary

EDIT: Title changed to better reflect my issue.

I am having trouble parsing a large body of text that includes line breaks and quotation marks from XML data. I'm running the parser through AppDelegate so that it pre-loads when the app is opened. My problem is that the text gets pulled in correctly in the parser didEndElement section, but when my view calls the text from the NSMutableArray from AppDelegate, \n and other html tags appear when they shouldn't. Screenshots are posted at the bottom of this question.

AppDelegate.h relevant code:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSXMLParser             *exhibitParser;
    NSMutableArray          *exhibitInfo;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSXMLParser    *exhibitParser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *exhibitInfo;

- (void) parseAllData;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ExhibitParser.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize exhibitParser, exhibitInfo;
@synthesize window = _window;

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    //delay to allow for splash screen    
    [self performSelector:@selector(parseAllData) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];  

    return YES;
}

- (void)parseAllData
{    
     exhibitParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website-Goes-Here.com/variable=%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"gallery_preference"]]]];

     ExhibitParser *exParser = [[ExhibitParser alloc] initExhibitParser];

     [exhibitParser setDelegate:exParser];
     //[parser parse];

     BOOL exsuccess = [exhibitParser parse];

     if(exsuccess)
     NSLog(@"No Exhibit Errors");
     else
     NSLog(@"Exhibit ERROR!!"); 

}
```

ExhibitParser.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class AppDelegate, ExhibitInfo;

@interface ExhibitParser : NSObject
{
    NSString            *currentExhibit;

    NSMutableString *descAttribute;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict;

    AppDelegate     *exAppDelegate;
    ExhibitInfo     *aExItems;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString            *currentExhibit;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString     *descAttribute;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dict;

@property (nonatomic, retain) ExhibitInfo          *aExItems;

- (ExhibitParser *) initExhibitParser;

@end
```

ExhibitParser.m:

(Note: The series of formatting in didEndElement takes the XML text and makes it look better on the iPad for us. The \n that's being written in here displays CORRECTLY as a line break in the NSLog that follows, but displays as literally "\n" once displayed in ExhibitView.)

```
#import "ExhibitParser.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ExhibitInfo.h"

@implementation ExhibitParser
@synthesize currentExhibit, descAttribute, dict, aExItems;

- (ExhibitParser *) initExhibitParser
{
    self = [super init];

    exAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentExhibit = [elementName copy];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ExhibitData"])
    {
        exAppDelegate.exhibitInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"exhibit"])
    {
        aExItems = [[ExhibitInfo alloc] init];

        dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        descAttribute = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    if ([attributeDict objectForKey:@"exhibitfact"]) 
    {
        descAttribute = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"exhibitfact"];
        [dict setObject:descAttribute forKey:@"exhibitfact"];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"exhibit"])
    {
        [exAppDelegate.exhibitInfo addObject:aExItems];
        [dict setObject:descAttribute forKey:@"exhibitfact"];

        //Formatting Series to make it pretty
        NSString *descriptionRaw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", descAttribute];
        NSString *descriptionFinal = [descriptionRaw stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"    " withString:@"\n"];
        NSString *descriptionEdited = [descriptionFinal stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];

        //This Log displays the text perfectly
        NSLog (@"%@", descriptionEdited);
        [aExItems setDescription:descriptionEdited];
    }


}

//I have read that foundCharacters can cause issues with hidden characters such as \n, so I've tried leaving this in and commenting it out. It seems to have no effect either way.

//- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
//{
//    
//    if([self.currentExhibit isEqualToString:@"description"])
//    {
//        [self.descAttribute appendString:string];
//    }
//}

@end
```

ExhibitInfo.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ExhibitInfo : NSObject
{
    NSString *description;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;

@end
```

ExhibitInfo.m:

```
#import "ExhibitInfo.h"

@implementation ExhibitInfo
@synthesize description;

@end
```

ExhibitView.m (where the text box is that will populate with the parsed data):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setTitle:@"Exhibit Information"];

    exAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    exhibitText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [exAppDelegate.exhibitInfo description]];

}
```

So where I'm getting totally brain smashed is that the NSLog in ExhibitParser.m displays the full body of text correctly, but in ExhibitView.m, when exhibitText.text is populated with what I believe should be identical to what's in the NSLog, it's not. It shows \n and opening  and closing () around the full body. Is this because it's being written to an NSMutableArray before getting called in ExhibitView? Why is there a difference between the NSLog and what the view shows?

Screenshot of the NSLog output - displayed correctly:
[image: NSLog (@"%@", descriptionEdited);]

Screenshot of how it displays in the view when the app runs (Note the parentheses at the beginning and end, the \n both from my formatting and from the line breaks, quotes at the beginning and end, and \ next to quotes in the middle of the text body):
[image: exhibitText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [exAppDelegate.exhibitInfo description]];]

Answer (score 1):

When you find your element try to remove new line character this way :

```
if ([attributeDict objectForKey:@"exhibitfact"]) 
        {
            descAttribute = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"exhibitfact"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/n" withString:@""];         

            [dict setObject:descAttribute forKey:@"exhibitfact"];
        }
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't really answer my question, which is why does it display perfectly in the NSLog instance I have, but not in the text box on the view. Your method does prevent the text "\n" from being displayed, but it doesn't create the line break it represents. The formatting that I used in didEndElement doesn't display extraneous code and interprets \n as a line break. (see screenshots). I can't see how to apply the method you provided to remove the parentheses that are displayed before and after. Thanks for the quick response. I'll mess around with this some more and report back.